# Python Code with Plugin "Create Points Layer from Spreadsheet"

Tags: python-3.x, spreadsheet, spatial, qgis

I'm new to python, that is the first problem.
Secondly I am trying to automate the task of adding vector point layers from spreadsheets (xlsx-files) with Python. 
The task can be done manually with the plugin "add spreadsheet layer".
I have a folder with roughly 20 xlsx-files that need to be added into the QGIS-project as vector point layers.
I have tried the following code snippet, to check if the core task of adding a spreadsheet layer actually works:

The Computer has a Win7 OS. The program in question is Python which is contained in the program QGIS 3.4.
The Plugin that I want to control through python is called "add spreadsheet layer".

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
processing.run("qgis:createpointslayerfromtable",
{'INPUT':r'C:\Users\Desktop\PlayItAll\Test.xlsx',
'XFIELD':'X_Pos',
'YFIELD':'Y_Pos',
'ZFIELD':None,
'MFIELD':None,
'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
'OUTPUT':r'memory'})
```

It produces this error:

```
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
```

I have contacted the programmer of the plugin and he gave me this code to try:

```
import processing
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:createpointslayerfromtable",
{
    'INPUT':r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Delete\test.xlsx',
    'XFIELD':'Longitude',
    'YFIELD':'Latitude',
    'ZFIELD':None,               
    'MFIELD':None,
    'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
    'OUTPUT':'memory'
})
```

For him it worked, for me it didn't.
I got this on the processing tab:

```
2019-07-03T13:19:43     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointsLayerFromTable.py", line 112, in processAlgorithm
              fields, wkb_type, target_crs)
             Exception: unknown


2019-07-03T13:19:43     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointsLayerFromTable.py", line 112, in processAlgorithm
              fields, wkb_type, target_crs)
             Exception: unknown

2019-07-03T13:19:43     CRITICAL     There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

The "python warnings" tab showed this:

```
2019-07-03T13:19:43     WARNING    warning:__console__:1: ResourceWarning:

             unclosed file


             traceback: File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 575, in runScriptEditor
              self.tabEditorWidget.currentWidget().newEditor.runScriptCode()
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_editor.py", line 629, in runScriptCode
              .format(filename.replace("\\", "/"), sys.getfilesystemencoding()))
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 635, in runCommand
              more = self.runsource(src)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 665, in runsource
              return super(ShellScintilla, self).runsource(source, filename, symbol)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 74, in runsource
              self.runcode(code)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
              exec(code, self.locals)
              File "", line 1, in
```

Comment: what is the message in the error log?

Comment: Hi Ian, I edited my question and added the error log.